# Ajax post opens new window with about:blank url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this Ajax post method which opens new window with data fine, but in URL field of a new window always stands about:blank. I want specific url to be written in url field.

```
    if (url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: array
        }).done(function (data) {
            var w = window.open();
            w.location.href = url;
            w.document.write(data);
            w.document.close();
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: So give it the url in the open method, if you are using a window, why use Ajax at all? Just post a form to a new window.

Comment: I tried that too, can you give me an example. I'm using codeigniter so i have to do some stuff in the controller and then return to ajax.

Comment: i tried window.open("http://www.example.com") but again it shows about:blank